# How to access vm.$el properties with single-file components?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, webpack-2

I'm trying to access the `clientHeight`property of a vue instance created by a single-file component, but it returns undefined. How can I do this?

```
<template lang='jade'>
  article#article.projectCard.relative.mb5.pa5( v-bind:style="styleObject")
    h3 {{ project.projectName }}
    p {{ project.projectDescription }}
</template> 

    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        project: '',
      },

      data () {
        return {
          styleObject: {
            backgroundColor: this.project.projectMainColor,
            height: '80vh'
          },
          cardHeight: this.clientHeight,
        };
      },
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the element after it's `mounted` with `this.$el` so you'd actually want `this.$el.clientHeight` after it's mounted.

You can do like:

```
data () {
  return {
    cardHeight: 0,
  }
}
```

Then do:

```
mounted () {
  this.cardHeight = this.$el.clientHeight + 'px'
}
```

Also, that `styleObject` would be better as a computed property. That way as things change it'll be automatically updated.

I'd personally do:

```
data () {
  return {
    cardHeight: '80vh',
  }
},

mounted () {
  this.cardHeight = this.$el.clientHeight + 'px'
},

computed: {
  styleObject () {
    return {
      backgroundColor: this.project.projectMainColor,
      height: this.cardHeight,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Even in the `mounted()` function, `this` is still `undefined`.  This appears to be a problem with single file components specifically.

Comment: It's really odd for `this` to be undefined. Are you sure it's not `this.$el` that's undefined? If so, you might be using an arrow function where you shouldn't.

Comment: You're absolutely right @bill-criswell I had `module: () => {}` instead of `module() {}` and that made all the difference.  Thank you!